# How to verify publish status via Google developer API?

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-publisher-tag

I'm simply looking to verify the status of my app publish request through the Google developer API, which you can easily see from the Google Play Console:
[Published Apps Request List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJSeT.png)

My problem is a 'fire and forget' approach that Google AndroidPublisher API has provided me with, were you build your **[Edit](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/)** - you upload your APK, modify your store listing etc etc... then you just commit.

Commit function:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/commit

**What I have implemented:**

> AndroidPublisher.java

```
// code removed for brevity
...
...


edit.validate();

edit.commit();
```

> AndroidAppEdit.java

```
public void validate() throws ProcessingFailedException {
    try {
        service.edits()
                .validate(packageName, editId)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ProcessingFailedException("Failed to validate the edit", e);
    }
}

public void commit() throws ProcessingFailedException {
    try {
        service.edits()
                .commit(packageName, editId)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ProcessingFailedException("Failed to commit the edit", e);
    }
}
```

**What I'm looking to achieve?**

The ability to poll an endpoint via REST or through a client library like [AndroidPublisher](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) to retrieve the state / status of my commit